# How to fetch the value of a column (for a particular row) when the column name is matched with a variable passed dynamically?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, procedure, callable-statement

I have the following table structure in Oracle database.
I want to find how many marks has ABC scored in Maths? The subject name is dynamic. It can change depending upon the input of the user.

Student Table:

```
Student_Id  Student_Name    Maths   English History Physics
1                ABC         93      89      90      70
2                XYZ         88      98      88      80
3                DEF         79      78      87      90
```

Is there a way to match the column name with a particular value fetched dynamically through User's Input?

Comment: Not sure that this actually needs to be solved in the query.  I assume the user would access a website to get those scores.  Then just code the frontend software to only show the score(s) s/he wants to see.

Comment: Your problem is the database. You would fare better, if you changed your data model to three tables: students (student_id, name), subjects (subject_id, name), student_subject (student_id, subject_id, grade). In your app you would offer the subjects read from the subjects table and the query would use the chosen subject's ID to get the grade. Very simple and easily extendable to more subjects (just more entries in the tables) or maybe grades per year (add a year column to the student_subject table).

Answer (score 2):

You should know what the columns are in the table.  Hence you can write the query using a `case` expression:

```
select (case when :input = 'Maths' then Maths
             when :input = 'English' then English
             when :input = 'History' then History
             when :input = 'Physics' then Physics
        end)  
from students
were Student_Name = 'ABC';
```

In fact, this question helps explain why it is better to store such data in *rows* rather than columns.  If your table were structured as:

Students:

```
Student_Id    Student_Name
    1            ABC 
    . . .
```

StudentMarks

```
Student_Id    Subject    Marks   
    1         Maths        93
    1         English      89
    1         History      90
    1         Physics      70
    . . .
```

(Note that you might also want a separate reference table for subjects as well.)

The query would be trivial with this data structure:

```
select sm.marks
from studentmarks sm join
     students s
     on sm.student_id = s.student_id
where subject = :input;
```

Such a structure would make it easy to add new subjects as well.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL is what you need. Here's an example:

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from student;

        ID NAM      MATHS    ENGLISH
---------- --- ---------- ----------
         1 ABC         93         89
         2 XYZ         88         98
         3 DEF         79         78
```

Function:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sum (par_subject IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4     l_str   VARCHAR2 (200);
  5     retval  NUMBER;
  6  BEGIN
  7     l_str :=
  8           'select sum('
  9        || DBMS_ASSERT.simple_sql_name (par_subject)
 10        || ') from student';
 11
 12     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str INTO retval;
 13
 14     RETURN retval;
 15  END;
 16  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT f_sum ('maths') FROM DUAL;

F_SUM('MATHS')
--------------
           260

SQL>
```

Comment: The OP asked "I want to find how many marks has ABC scored in Maths?" This finds the total score across a subject rather than an individual's score.

Comment: Ah, yes. OK then, you showed how to do that, here's how it might have been done if the question was different.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need dynamic SQL or even PL/SQL. You can do it in an SQL query using `UNPIVOT`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( Student_Id, Student_Name, Maths, English, History, Physics ) AS
SELECT 1, 'ABC', 93, 89, 90, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'XYZ', 88, 98, 88, 80 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'DEF', 79, 78, 87, 90 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT score
FROM   test_data
UNPIVOT ( score FOR subject IN ( Maths, English, History, Physics ) )
WHERE subject      = 'MATHS'
AND   student_name = 'ABC'
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | SCORE |
> | ----: |
> |    93 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e8f1563965e28ea07bbe3df4c31d4123)*

If you want to use a PL/SQL Function then you still don't need dynamic SQL and could just wrap the above query or use a `CASE` statement, as below:

**PL/SQL Function**:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION getScore(
  i_student_name IN TEST_DATA.STUDENT_NAME%TYPE,
  i_subject      IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  p_score NUMBER(3,0);
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE i_subject
         WHEN 'MATHS' THEN Maths
         WHEN 'ENGLISH' THEN English
         WHEN 'HISTORY' THEN History
         WHEN 'PHYSICS' THEN Physics
         END
  INTO p_score
  FROM   test_data
  WHERE  student_name = i_student_name;

  RETURN p_score;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT getScore( 'ABC', 'MATHS' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | GETSCORE('ABC','MATHS') |
> | ----------------------: |
> |                      93 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=80397c5749ddd1dcea4f2ab38a10ecdd)*

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is one more approach using `xmlquery` as following:

> ```
> SELECT      
>       to_number(xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
>         passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
>           'select '|| <subject_name> || ' as c '
>           || 'from test_data WHERE student_name = ''' 
>           || <student_name>  || ''''))
>       returning content)) as marks
>     FROM dual;
> ```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5ecfdd1d469621e877b77db6c1157332)

Cheers!!